# Is mustard oil safe for consumption?

Tags: food-safety

Some Indian cuisines require mustard oil as an ingredient. However, I cannot find any FDA approved mustard oil, and most of the bottles quote "for external use only."

Is it possible to find FDA approved mustard oil? Or, is it unsafe to consume mustard oil?

Comment: A quick trip to Amazon finds mustard oil with erucic acid removed. Whether that is necessary for health or not, I have no idea (though, obviously, the fact that people eat it puts an upper limit on the toxicity), but I believe erucic acide is what the FDA objects to. Also, I have no idea of the flavor & cooking effects of that removal. http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00348JBFU/

Comment: pure mustard oil is absolutely rich in taste, in fact some Indian cuisines are especially prepared in that like chokha, kadhi etc as its usage enhances the deliciousness of the cuisine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the following information in [a thread on Mamta's Kitchen forum](http://www.mamtaskitchen.com/board/showthread.php?thread_id=129):

> Because it is EU-designated external use only, [mustard oil] is therefore exempt from shipping regulations that would apply to foods. Thus, it can be shipped in a container truck that had previously contained, say, motor oil, or even something worse. This probably was the cause of the poisonings, because people have been consuming mustard oil for millennia without ill effect despite the current EU designation – which seems to be causing greater problems than it is trying to save us from.

I haven't personally verified this statement, but if true, it's best to avoid the "for external use" oil.

Comment: +1, Thanks. I understand that though the product might be safe, because of logistics, it is best to avoid it - unless it organic/locally made.

Answer (score 4):

you should purchase it from online stores which deal with edible mustard oil, and obviously the mustard oil which is quoted for "external uses" that is not for consumption.

Comment: here is link you can have organic mustard oil http://www.downtoearthorganic.com/products/138-mustard-oil.aspx

Comment: Some varieties of perfectly edible mustard oil are labelled "for external use" in Europe since Europe considers it unsafe :)